# chroot with mounts in unprivileged container

Tags: mount, docker, chroot

How can I create a mount inside a Docker container as root but without `--privileged` mode? The purpose is getting a chroot with `/proc`, and `/dev` mounted inside a container.

I can do so with `chroot` and `mount` commands given a container in `--privileged` mode, but I am looking for workarounds that do not require it.

This is for build purposes and I can accept some performance hit or other limitations.

I am looking along the lines of `LD_PRELOAD`, `proot`, `pseudo`, `fakeroot`, but had no luck so far. Is there any way?

Comment: This sounds like you might be trying to do something which could be done entirely without chroots or mounting `/proc` and `/dev`; could you give some more context?

Comment: My environment is a Docker container provided by a CI environment which gives me no --privileged mode. Inside of that environment, I need to create a new rootfs using debootstrap, then install packages using chroot. Some packages require /proc or /dev to install successfully.

Answer (score 0):

[proot](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/proot.1.html) worked for me in an unprivileged Docker container:

```
proot -w / -S /path/to/root bash
```

Maybe you didn't pass all of the options you needed?